# How to set flexible th and tr in table ? using Bootstrap or pure css?

Tags: html, css

I have table

```css
.table { 

} 
       th {
            color: $gray;
            font-weight: 500;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: none; 
        }
    
        tr:nth-child(odd){  
        background-color:rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
      }


      tr {
        // max-height: 34px; 
        max-height: 34px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap; 
    }
    
        td {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        max-height: 34px; 
        padding: .75rem 0 .75rem .75rem;
        border-top: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        
    }
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th> Id </th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 1long 1text 1long 1text 1long 1text need be flexible</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma long text long textlong textlong textlong text</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Do you notice a problem with table. I just want it if, for example, my ID or any other field requires more width to be flexible.

if tr 'Company' have one word  set a small width, but if for example a company has 200 characters length, set all lines wide to fit those 200 characters.

I intentionally posted this long text to notice the difference. It all needs to be flexible.

My wish is for the tables to remain and not for me to have to change into divs

Answer (score 0):

Try this Bootstrap code! It's pretty easy, and It handles every thing you need.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container"> 
  <table class="table">

    <thead>
     <tr>
    <th> Id </th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th> 
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1 1long 1text 1long 1text 1long 1text need be flexible</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma long text long textlong textlong textlong text</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td> 
  </tr> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i want to my Id td or tr if don't have much characters length be small. More precisely, if he doesn't need a lot of space, don't take it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use table, you can't use `display: flex;` on table elements. Table elements native use `display: table;`. Add child `div` inside `td` elements if you want to style it using flexbox or prevent text wrapping.

```css
       th {
            color: $gray;
            font-weight: 500;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: none; 
        }
    
        tr:nth-child(odd){  
        background-color:rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
      }


      tr {
        // max-height: 34px; 
        max-height: 34px;
    }
    
        td div {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        max-height: 34px; 
        padding: .75rem 0 .75rem .75rem;
        border-top: none;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th> Id </th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 1long 1text 1long 1text 1long 1text need be flexible</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><div>Centro comercial Moctezuma long text long textlong textlong textlong text</div></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Maria but i want to my Id td or tr if don't have much characters length be small. More precisely, if he doesn't need a lot of space, don't take it

Comment: Did you even try this? https://jsfiddle.net/5L37zkc9/   
Tables automatically shrink columns to shortest width possible

Comment: I have any issuse here.. I need to try once again